# How do I handle the Apply button in live wallpaper settings?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have a live wallpaper. I bring up the Preview activity and I see two buttons at the bottom Apply and Settings. Pressing the Settings button brings me into my settings activity where the user can modify the wallpaper's preferences.

When the user exits the settings activity and goes back to the 'Preview' activity, the changes take effect in the preview. If the user DOES NOT hit apply, (and simply back, for example), the settings are applied anyway.

How does one handle a user pressing the 'Apply' button? This is added automatically by Android
and is not in the xml.